# Can kinetic energy broken down into its components ? Even if it is scalar?

Tags: energy, kinetic-theory, degrees-of-freedom

I'm confused while reading about degrees of freedom. According to what I read the number of degrees of freedom (DOF) of a monoatomic gas is 3 at low temperature. My question is: is that
1) because the molecule is moving in three dimensional space then we can have three components of velocity so we are saying DOF is 3

or

2) it can able to move in the x, y and z direction so DOF is 3

Which is correct, 1st or 2nd?

Comment: How is "the velocity has three components" different from "the particle can move in three directions"?

Comment: Sorry I am wrong I written it in hurry I know velocity has only two dimensions

Comment: I know velocity can not have three components but see in Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem

Comment: I know but see in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem.    (Below the Translation energy and ideal gasses) it is written.  The (Newtonian) kinetic energy of a particle of mass m, velocity v is given by

{\displaystyle H_{\text{kin}}={\tfrac {1}{2}}m|\mathbf {v} |^{2}={\tfrac {1}{2}}m\left(v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2}+v_{z}^{2}\right),} H_{{{\text{kin}}}}={\tfrac  12}m|{\mathbf  {v}}|^{2}={\tfrac  {1}{2}}m\left(v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2}+v_{z}^{2}\right),
"where vx, vy and vz are the Cartesian components of the velocity v."

Comment: I'm still unclear what you think is the difference between options (1) and (2).

Comment: @SunuKodag I, too, see  no difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: @SunuKodag You need to use MathJax

Comment: No 2 does not make sense. It can move in any direction, not just in 3. There is an infinite number of directions it can move in. But no matter what the direction of velocity is, it can be described by three components in a Cartesian system.